# How do i get the dates for the whole month in a dropdown? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the dates to be in a dropdown format.

i have created something that'll display 3 days but i would like to create a loop for it and i am not sure how.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM/dd"), DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM/dd"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(li);
            ListItem li2 = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MMM/dd"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MMM/dd"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(li2);
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(li2);
            ListItem li3 = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("MMM/dd"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("MMM/dd"));
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(li3);
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(li3);
```

i would like the dropdown to have the date for the whole month from current date.

Comment: When you say "whole month", do you mean to the 1st day of the current month?

Comment: @jefftrotman i mean a one month span. For example: 19 June till 19 May. It should be backdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dtmCurrent = DateTime.Today;
var dtmLimit = dtmCurrent.AddMonths(-1);
while(dtmCurrent >= dtmLimit)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem(dtm.ToString("MMM/dd"), dtm.ToString("MMM/dd"));
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
    DropDownList2.Items.Add(li);
    dtmCurrent = dtmCurrent.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
var numberOfDays = startDate.Subtract(startDate.AddMonths(-1)).Days;

for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfDays; i++)
{
    ListItem li = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1*i).ToString("MMM/dd"), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1*i).ToString("MMM/dd"));
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
    DropDownList2.Items.Add(li);
}
```